# Are there any major differences between the original Scintilla and ScnitillaNet control?

Tags: c#, .net, scintilla

I'm trying to create an editor to support speech for Windows and now trying to figure out if I should use ScintillaNet or original Scintilla as my base. Will greatly appreciate if anyone can tell me if there are any major differences between them and what they are. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is not much point in contemplating the "original Scintilla", it was written in C.  You cannot directly use code written in C in your C# project, you have to use pinvoke.  So you'll end up writing a set of C# classes that hides that ugly pinvoke code.  And re-invent ScintillaNET.

If you need to adapt the ScintillaNET wrappers then that's possible, source code is available.  Just don't start from scratch, the C interface is *not* pretty.